# Copy a list of files in one file list to another folder

Tags: linux, xargs

Below is the content of a file **list.txt**

```
Source/GEPON/DOCSIS/C3160/2.2.0/src/com/xxx/ems/Log_en_US.xml
Source/GEPON/DOCSIS/C3160/2.2.0/src/com/xxx/ems/Log_zh_CN.xml
```

Source is under folder A;
Now I want to copy these two files into another folder B;meanwhile keeping the parent folder substructure.
I used `xargs -a list.txt cp -t B`;
got the two files under one folder B without their parent folders.
What do I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `--parents` option to `cp` but that requires you to move between directories.

```
cd A; xargs -a ../list.txt cp --parents -t ../B
```

Comment: Sorry, I left it in from my own testing.  The `-v` or `--verbose` option causes `cp` to print the actions it takes.  I removed it from the answer now.